# register enable line usage in `case` block (verilog synthesis for altera cpld)

Tags: verilog, intel-fpga, programmable-logic, quartus

I have the following in a verilog design aimed at an altera CPLD (currently targeting EPM240, although the target device isn't set in stone):

```
always @(posedge clk)
    if (we)
    begin
        case (rw_sel)
           3'd0: reg0 <= data_in;
           3'd1: reg1 <= data_in;
           ...
        endcase
    end
```

I assumed that this would synthesize a design where `rw_sel` was decoded into a number of different select lines, which would be 'and'ed with `we`, and then connected to the enable input of the register.

However, this isn't what has been done: examining the results in the RTL viewer, the `we` line has been connected directly to the enable inputs of every register, then the data input of each register is connected to a mux2 that selects from either the incoming data or the current value of the register.

Isn't this much less space-efficient than the design I was expecting?  And if so, how can I persuade Quartus to generate the more efficient version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't this much less space-efficient than the design I was expecting?

No; it's actually better.

Consider the structure of the LE in the MAX II CPLD (from [MAX II Architecture](https://www.altera.com/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/max2/max2_mii51002.pdf)). I've highlighted an important detail:

[image]

The input to the register's clock enable **does not pass through the LUT**. It must be driven by one of the two clock enable signals which are shared across the LAB.

Your design would require each register to be implemented in a separate LAB, which will run you out of space very rapidly. The synthesizer's design allows each of the registers to be implemented within a single LE, probably all within a single LAB.

Comment: Yes, I was just reading through the data sheet and came to the same conclusion.  And not only that, but the mux it's using, which I was assuming would require a separate LE to implement, is actually a fixed part of the LE (shown in the top left of the schematic, on the data3 line into the LUT), so uses no resources at all to implement.

Comment: Not quite. That's a configuration MUX -- its value can't be changed at runtime. Still, implementing a mux in the LUT is easy.